What does tag(s) mean?

While I was adding gpg to my favourite tags, I saw there was no number mentioned besides the tag. If I search and add other tags, they present numbers like key-rotation(10) which means 10 questions with this tag, but what does gpg(s) mean ?

The s is short for synonym. It is shown whenever a tag is synonymous to another tag.
When you click the tag link gpg you will notice it redirects to to PGP tag page. (This kind of redirect happens for all synonyms, which can be handy if, for example,  you're not aware of other terminologies.)
Since we handle GPG as a synonym of PGP, the system shows that (s) instead of a question count. That's because technically, all GPG related questions are sorted under the PGP tag — which does show the number of related questions.
In your case, you might as well favorite the PGP tag.

gpg is a synonym of pgp.
